# Majoration of an integral depending a parameter (beta function)

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals, upper-lower-bounds

I would like to bound the following integral with an upper bound depending on $a\in[0,1]$ when $a$ is close to 1:

$$\int_a^1\frac{t^{\frac{r-3}{2}}}{\sqrt{1-t}}dt$$ where $r\ge 5$ is an integrer.

I have tried integration by parts with some steps.
I  also computed numerically, it seems that the dependance with $a$ is exponential close to 1.

Comment: If we denote $\alpha=\frac{r-3}2;\,\alpha>1$, then
$$I(\alpha, a)=\int_a^1\frac{t^\alpha}{\sqrt{1-t}}dt=\int_0^{1-a}\frac{(1-x)^\alpha}{\sqrt x}dx=2\int_0^\sqrt{1-a}(1-t^2)^\alpha dt$$
At $t\ll1$ we are allowed to decompose the integrand into the series. Integrating term by term
$$I(\alpha, a)\sim2\int_0^\sqrt{1-a}\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\binom{\alpha}{k}t^{2k}\,dt=2\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\binom{\alpha}{k}\frac{(1-a)^\frac{2k+1}{2}}{2k+1}$$
$$=2\left(\sqrt{1-a}-\frac{\alpha}{1!\cdot3}(1-a)^\frac32+\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)}{2!\cdot5}(1-a)^\frac52-...\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

If you invoke the Gausssian hypergeometric function, assuming that I am not mistaken, the integral is
$$I=\sqrt{\pi } \,\frac{\Gamma
   \left(\frac{r-1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(\frac{r}{2}\right)}-\frac{2 a^{\frac{r-1}{2}}
   }{r
   -1}\,\
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{r-1}{2};\frac{r+1}{2};a\right)$$

Expanded as series around $a=1^-$
$$\color{blue}{ I=t-\frac{r-3}{24} t^3+\frac{(r-5) (r-3)}{640} 
   t^5+O\left(t^7\right)}\quad \text{with} \quad  \color{blue}{  t=2 \sqrt{1-a}}$$

Trying for $r=8$ and $a=\frac9{10}$ this gives
$$I=\frac{2209}{1200 \sqrt{10}}=0.582123$$ while the exact value is
$$I=\frac{381}{1000}+\frac{5 \pi }{16}-\frac{5}{8} \tan ^{-1}(3)=0.582094$$

This does not look as an exponential behaviour.

If you are concerned by approximations of $I$, we could have much better using more terms in the series to be later transformed into a $[n+1,n]$ Padé approximant $P_n$. For the worked example, $P_4$ gives an absolute error of $2.21\times 10^{-8}$.